# Getting an InvalidOperationException for accessing View when trying to access Controller Function

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Fairly new to MVC, Supporting Code that generally works but is generating excessive Server errors.  The Server errors take the form of:

```
Exception information: 
    Exception type: InvalidOperationException 
    Exception message: The view 'RenderProthyPDF' or its master was not     found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations  were searched:
~/Views/Portal/RenderProthyPDF.aspx
~/Views/Portal/RenderProthyPDF.ascx
~/Views/Shared/RenderProthyPDF.aspx
~/Views/Shared/RenderProthyPDF.ascx
~/Views/Portal/RenderProthyPDF.cshtml
~/Views/Portal/RenderProthyPDF.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/RenderProthyPDF.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/RenderProthyPDF.vbhtml
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult.FindView(ControllerContext context)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
   at  System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext  controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
```

However  'RenderProthyPDF is not a view, but a function within a controller:

Example calling code in the cshtml:

```
<a class="document-link" href="javascript:markLastVisitedCaseDocument('@currentDocument.WorkingDocumentURL'); renderProthyPDF('@currentDocument.DktYear', '@currentDocument.DktSequence', '@currentDocument.WorkingDocumentURL');">
```

and

```
<a class="tile" style="height: 130px;" href="javascript:renderProthyPDF('@d.DktYear', '@d.DktSequence', '@d.URL');">
```

The referenced javascript:

```
    renderProthyPDF = function (rDktYear, rDktSequence, rURL) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        async: false,
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("RenderProthyPDF", "Portal")',
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify({ Year : rDktYear,
                           Sequence : rDktSequence,
                  prothyDocumentURL : rURL
        }),
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        failure: function (errMsg) {
            alert(errMsg);
        }
    });
```

And the C# code (In JPortal\Controllers\PortalController.cs):

```
        public ActionResult RenderProthyPDF(string Year, string Sequence, string prothyDocumentURL, PortalCaseView viewmodel)
    {
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("renderingPDF", "true");
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("renderingURL", prothyDocumentURL);

        return View();
    }
```

What should I do to prevent these errors from being generated?  What is going wrong?

Edit:  Am specifying directories I have:

The referenced hyperlinks are in the partial views in 
    JPortal\Views\Shared_.cshtml

The main view (the javascript code) is in:
    JPortal\Views\Portal\Case.cshtml

The ActionResult function is in
    JPortal\Conrollers\PortalController.cs

Answer (score 1):

Isn't the error message clear enough as it's saying that it couldn't find a view file named `RenderProthyPDF.cshtml` in the below path it searched for

```
~/Views/Portal/*
~/Views/Shared/*
```

In your controller Action method `RenderProthyPDF` you are saying `return View();` which is going to look for a view with the same name as of action method which it's not able to find and thus the error.

if you don't have the view then generate one (or) if you have created the view with a different name then pass that name to the `View()` method like (since one of the overload for `View()` method accepts the view name as `string` argument)

```
return View("MydifferentNamedRenderProthyPDF");
```

Comment: Not intuitively obvious to me. The RenderProthyPDF function is called from multiple Views so how would I know what view to return it to?

Comment: Should I be returning something other than a View() result?

Comment: Check your views folder and see if you have a view file named `RenderProthyPDF`?